# android.app.Application cannot be cast to my application

Tags: android, classcastexception

I have few percent crashes when application from start points (launch activity, receivers) cannot be cast to my application.

My launch activity:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        (application as MyApp)
        ...
    }
```

My app extends MultiDexApplication:

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {
...
```

Crash log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.my.myapp.MyApp
    at com.my.myapp.prelogin.presentation.LaunchActivity.onCreate(LaunchActivity.kt:59)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I spent a lot of time looking for this problem, but could not find a solution. I think it's trouble in android sdk.

*p.s. I have **name** tag on manifest file*

Comment: Why are you casing application? What are you trying to do? What class does MyApp extend?

Comment: You'll have to show your MyApp class, see if it extends platform's Application class

Comment: My app extends MultiDexApplication which extends android.app.Application. 
In fact i use application to get dagger component. I specifically simplified the example. 
My application works fine. 
This crash is 10-20 times per day of 60k active daily users. This is very small. But i want to find a reason this error

Comment: I also found statistics on android versions: 
Android 6.0.1 - 37%,
6.0 - 22%,
9 - 19%

Comment: Do you allow backups in your AndroidManifest.xml? The see this article: https://medium.com/@pablobaxter/what-happened-to-my-subclass-android-application-924c91bafcac

Answer (score 5):

Do this in your Manifest file

```
<application
        android:name="your.Packagename.CpuSpyApp"
```